# Event to know which outlook window got focus when user switches between multiple windows of outlook in vsto plugin

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

I am working on an outlook vsto plugin, suppose there are multiple inspectors of outlook opened(e.g. mails,appointments). I want an EVENT to know when user switches to different inspector using ALT+Tab, or Which inspector got focus.
what i want to achieve is am Enabling/Disabling a ribbon button by checking the kind of Item opened in inspector like if Appointment item (button enabled) else (disabled).
I have achieved half of the task by setting button enabled in Appointment_open() event.
the problem start arising when user moved to another inspector of outlook using ALT+Tab then the ribbon button is left enabled.
if i get the event of which inspector got focus i can set the enabled property to true or false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Application.ActiveExplorer` / `ActiveInspector` properties.

Both `Inspector` and `Explorer` objects expose the `Activate` event.

Comment: Dmitry Streblechenko   as far as i know Activate is a method which brings that particular inspector in foreground.
I want to know about an event when any inspector got focus by user action such as Alt+Tab

Comment: There is also an event by the same name - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.inspector.activate(even) . You can see it fire in OutlookSpy (http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/)  - open an inspector, click the Inspector button on the OutlookSpy ribbon, go to the Events tab, see the log at the bottom of the window.

Comment: Binding Activate event is not working , recently read about wrapping all the inspector and then binding child event on each of them would do the trick. working on it hope that solution will work

Comment: I am still not sure why you need that event. If you want the active inspector when processing a particular action, just use Application.ActiveInspector. If you are processing a callback from a ribbon, all even handlers give you a context, which will be an inspector in case of inspector ribbon controls.

Comment: I think there is some misunderstanding. what i want to achieve is suppose i have multiple inspectors in outlook (MailItem or AppointmentItem). according to the type of inspector user is present we enable/ disable ribbon button. i want to know when user switches to another insecpector using ui or alt+tab . means if jumped to apoinment then enable else disable. so i want to know the event where i can catch which insector got focus

Comment: Again, when a visible/enabled/etc. callbacks fire, you get RibbonControl object passed to your callback, cast RibbonControl.Context to Inspector, then use Inspector.CurrentItem to figure out which control belongs to which item.